# SMTP connection failed when set the username not email format

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, mailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send emails, when I set the config using a username not following email format it does not work. I use the same config on outlook to connect and it works fine.

```
"mail" => "smtp",
              "smtp"  => [
                  "host" => "mail.domain.com",
                  "port" => 25,
                  "auth" => true,
                  "secure" => "", // No need for ssl secure here
                  "user" => 'domain\username',
                  "pass" => 'P@$$w0rd'
              ]
```

I have another mailer config but the username is username@domain.com and it is working fine.

The error that I got is:

```
> SMTP connect() failed.
> https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: It’s quite likely you need to escape that backslash in the username string. Try `domain\\username`.

Comment: @Synchro I did it. I got the same error

Comment: The code you have posted is not part of PHPMailer. It would help if you showed us how it is used. Setting `SMTPDebug = 2` on the PHPMailer instance will let you know more about why it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I upgrade the PHPMailer version it worked. Also, there was server issues they allowed requests from outside the list of IPs.